# RSSの内容が文字化けしてしまう

Tags: monaca

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
monacaでRSSを取得するサンプルを使ってアプリを開発したいのですが
文字化けしてしまいます。

<サンプル>
https://github.com/monaca/project-templates/tree/master/4-jqm-memo
変更点は以下の通りです。
<変更前>index.htmlの13行目
var feedUrl = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml";

<変更後1>facebook→titleの文字化け(世界のtoyota様)
var feedUrl = "http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=158139660914197&format=rss20";
変更・・・[http://www.lottaleben.de/tools/rss-feed-fuer-facebook-seiten-generieren/で作成](http://www.lottaleben.de/tools/rss-feed-fuer-facebook-seiten-generieren/%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90)

<変更後2>ameba→取得年月日の文字化け(エビちゃん)
var feedUrl = "http://rssblog.ameba.jp/ebizo-ichikawa/rss.html";
変更・・・var feedUrl = "[http://rssblog.ameba.jp/(アメーバID)/rss.html](http://rssblog.ameba.jp/(%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90ID)/rss.html)";

誠に恐れ入りますが、ご教授の程宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 文字化け？というか「TOYOTA / トヨタ自動車株式会社&apos;s Facebook Wall 」こんな文字が表示される感じでしょうか？

Comment: @turutosiyaさま
レス頂きましてありがとうございます。
T社とは別の記事ですが、題名のみ文字化けします(facebookの場合)。アメーバブログですと、日にちだけ文字化けしてしまいます

Comment: さん、文字化けの状況を、質問に貼り付けるなどし、具体的に記載頂くと、回答しやすいかもしれません。

Comment: @turutosiyaさま
レス頂きましてありがとうございます。位置がおかしくなってしまいましたが質問の上に画像を添付しました。

Comment: 「数値文字参照」というものなので、 https://gist.github.com/myaumyau/4975024 の `decNumRefToString` で文字に変換してみてはどうでしょう？